# When does 负面 or 正面 go before 影响, and when does it go afterwards?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, sentence

Sometimes I'll see text saying that something 影响负面 another thing, and other times I'll see that something 负面影响 another. Is there a rule or concrete grammatical basis to determine which sentence uses a particular structure?

Comment: Do you have an example of the use of 影响负面 in an article? Only heard here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native Chinsese speaker, I never use either as a verb.

When we use “负面影响”, we think this is a noun, so it can be something has 负面影响 to something.

For example 小明的大声吵闹对小红有负面影响 (Ming's loud noise has 负面影响 to Hong). 对 means "to", which shows the target of the neagative influence.

When we use “影响负面”, what we actually want to express is “影响是负面的”，so we even do not use 影响负面 in Chinese. The real usage can be

小明的大声吵闹影响负面 ===> 小明的大声吵闹的影响是负面的.

I think which one to use doesn't matter, people can absolutely know what you mean. However, the order to place "影响" or "负面" is actually no solid rules, it's flexible in Chinese language...

Comment: I'm confused by the word "neither". "Neither" means you never use these terms. But then you go on to say you do use them. So I think you probably meant to write "either". I think a small edit would be helpful here.

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler Sorry, in this question's decription `saying that something 影响负面 another thing, and other times I'll see that something 负面影响 another`, which use both `影响负面` and `负面影响` as a verb in the context. When I say I use neither, I mean I never use any of them as a verb. For example,  I shall never use `我负面影响你` or `我影响负面你`

Comment: So maybe your answer could say: `... I never use either as a verb.`
?

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler Yes！

Answer (score 2):

负面影响 = downside/negative influence, the meaning of this well-known noun phrase is clear by itself, and can be expressed by the pattern - A negatively influences B possesses the characteristics of (C). For example:

- "不充分的睡眠"(A)對"學習䏻力"(B)**有**"负面影响"(C). - Inadequate sleep **has** a negative impact on learning ability.

On the other hand, 影响负面 = influence downside/negative, the meaning is unclear by looking at the words along, so let's try to make a sentence similar to the above:

- "不充分睡眠的影响负面"(A)**是**"學習䏻力"(B)降低 - The negative impact from inadequate sleep **is** the lowered learning ability.

The pattern here is (A) results in (B), which is quite different from the previous example. Hope you can see the differences between 负面影响 and 影响负面 from the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, 负面影响 is a noun phrase comprised of an adjective 负面 "negative" and a noun 影响 "influence, effect"

whereas 影响负面 syntactically is a sentence "influence is negative", where the verb-to-be is not needed in Chinese. In actual usage, though, this short sentence does require some elaboration as to what influence we are talking about. It usually comes in the form of X 對 Y 的影响负面.

These two are not interchangeable.